# Tiny question about what's happening here (how getline works)

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a file name:\n";
    string filename;

    cin >> filename;
    cout << cin.tellg();
    //cin.seekg(0);
    ofstream ost(filename);

    for (string line; getline(cin, line);)
    {
        cout << cin.tellg();
        
        if (line == "t") break;
        cout << "Enter a line or press 't' to terminate.\n";
        ost << line << '\n';
    }
}
```

If I run this code with the `cin.seekg(0)` commented and this is the output:

```
4648Enter a line or press 't' to terminate.
```

Just wrote a random string here (`"tkewtytoryrtputrkgpgtrkytrp"`) just a long string with no spaces and what's important is that the for loop is being entered and `"enter a line or press 't' to terminate"` is being outputted, so I am assuming this happens because `cin >>` reads the first string but then we still have a newline there so `getline` sees that and goes oh ok I stop reading if I see a newline so it enters the for loop, but now if I enter the exact same string without the `cin.seekg(0)` commented this is the output:

```
46
```

Just 46, then it asks for me input because I'm in the `getline` loop but it doesn't enter it yet. My question is, we were at 46 a second ago right? What exactly is going to 0 doing? And why does it make all this work? If I go to 0 wouldn't that just read the string I typed again or has that already been extracted? And if it has then what exactly is at 0? I'm going from position 46 to position 0 I just don't really understand what position 0 looks like?

I'm just thinking that at first the buffer was:
`"yportyitrytpuykutu\n"` then the string got extracted and the buffer was just `"\n"` but that cant be the case because in the first case it got to position 48 so can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: I don't think it's valid to seek within the standard input stream.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? I think they have some extensions, like flushing `stdin`, which is otherwise UB. Perhaps this is one of them.

Comment: Yeah I am using visual studio but like paddy said I just did some research and found that yeah I can't/shouldn't really seek in the stdin stream

Comment: All `tellg` will give you is a value you can later use to return to the same point in the stream with `seekg`. It doesn't promise that the value given is actually useful. The data at that location may not be the same. Picture a stream wrapped around a circular buffer, for example. Positions keep being reused. You also get neat little caveats like [*seekg(n) is not necessarily equivalent to seekg(n, ios::beg).*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg#Notes)